# Using Tweepy (Twitter API) to return list of users where name contains .btc

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I'm learning tweepy.

Have been doing some testing and using the get_users.py from github.  It enables me to bring back information based on user_ids ie

`user_ids = [2244994945, 6253282]`

This is handy but I'm trying to display a list of users the meet a certain criteria, ie end in .BTC

I'm wondering if anyone knows if the get_users is suitable for this and how it should be specified?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `search_users` method ([see here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#follow-search-and-get-users)), but there is no way to build a query like the one you're asking for. The only workaround I see would be to use this method to search for `.btc` and then process the results to keep only the account that meet your criteria.

Comment: Thanks Mickael,  I was just looking at that one but noticed that API is also limited to 1000 but it did somewhat do what I needed it to, it seemed to also bring back a combination of username and name.  I have seen other sites that are able to produce 10k+ users so not sure how they are overcoming it.  I have an elevated developer account but a little bit stuck.

Comment: @theethers You should maybe contact those sites to ask them how they are doing it, but I am pretty sure that this not with the Twitter official API (or maybe they run the search at regular intervals and store the users that match the requirements. That can work if the search results change regularly... and if the users rarely update their name).